# How to build OpenCV for Android using libc++ STL library?

Tags: opencv, stl, android-ndk, libc++

I would like to build a OpenCV from source using a libc++ STL library, instead of default GNU STL. LibC++ offers better C++11 and C++14 support. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tested this with OpenCV 2.4.7 and Android NDK r10d.

First, you need to download [OpenCV source](http://opencv.org/downloads.html). Unpack the source and replace the platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake with [version that suppports libc++](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25682802/android.toolchain.cmake).

Now, open `modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp` and change line 69 from

```
(defined __GNUC__ && defined _STLPORT_MAJOR)
```

to

```
(defined __GNUC__ && (defined _STLPORT_MAJOR || defined _LIBCPP_VERSION))
```

Next, in folder platforms/scripts create a script cmake_android_arm_libcxx.sh with following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`/..

mkdir -p build_android_arm
cd build_android_arm

cmake -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 -DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-8 -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=OFF -DBUILD_JASPER=OFF -DBUILD_OPENEXR=OFF -DBUILD_PACKAGE=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=OFF -DBUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_androidcamera=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_contrib=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_legacy=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ml=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_nonfree=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_photo=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ts=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_video=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Os -DNDEBUG -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-all" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Os -DNDEBUG -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-all -fvisibility-inlines-hidden" -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DWITH_EIGEN=OFF -DWITH_JASPER=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_TIFF=OFF -DWITH_TBB=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../android/android.toolchain.cmake $@ ../..
```

If you want, you can tweak the parameters of the script (i.e. what is built and how).

Finally, export the path to your NDK build folder

```
export ANDROID_NDK=~/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10d/
```

and execute the script:

```
 sh ./scripts/cmake_android_arm_libcxx.sh
```

Now enter to `build_android_arm` folder and build the OpenCV:

```
cd build_android_arm
make -j9
```

The libjpeg, libpng and other 3rd party libraries will appear in `platforms/build_android_arm/3rdparty/lib` and opencv libraries will appear in `platforms/build_android_arm/lib` folder.

This has been tested on Mac OS X 10.10, OpenCV 2.4.7 and Android NDK r10d.

Comment: do have you update your project to OpenCV 3? That line doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Not yet, but planning to have one next week or week after next. The reason for this is that recently released NDK r11 has deprecated GCC and stdc++ in favour of Clang and libc++.

Comment: @JoseUrbanoDuarteJunior, I've built OpenCV 3.0 with clang and libc++ without any modifications to code. I simply works out of the box (no need to modify `operations.hpp`.

Comment: I forgot to say that you need to use NDK r10e, because in r11 structure of folders has changed so android cmake toolchain no longer works. However, there is a [workaround for this](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake/issues/81).

Comment: Have you compile for MIPS? Can you post how you did it?

Comment: Yes, I've compiled for all 7 ABIs using the same configuration params. The only exception was mips64 which had to be built with GCC (but still against libc++).
Btw. are there any mips and mips64 devices to test with? I haven't found yet a single mips64 device, and only two mips devices.

Comment: Nice! Could you share your code for compiling for all different versions? I tried to just change the tool chain, but didn't work. Right now, I have it compile for armv7, x86 and armeabi. I don't have devices for testing.

Comment: @JoseUrbanoDuarteJunior, I cannot add it as a comment so I've added it as another answer.

Comment: @DoDo your version of android.toolchain.cmake that suppports libc++ is a dead link. can you re-upload it ?

Comment: @Erwan, that was 3 years ago. In the meantime Android NDK added official CMake toolchain which can be used to build OpenCV - I use that now. I don't have this old toolchain anymore.

Comment: @DoDo thanks for your answer I don't even try to use the official android.toolchain.cmake file

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script which I used to build OpenCV 3.0 with clang and libc++ for arm64 (for other ABI's just change toolchain name):

```
#!/bin/sh

export ANDROID_NDK=~/android-sdks/android-ndk
cmake -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=aarch64-linux-android-clang3.5 -DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a" -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-8 -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=OFF -DBUILD_JASPER=OFF -DBUILD_OPENEXR=OFF -DBUILD_PACKAGE=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Os -DNDEBUG -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-all" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Os -DNDEBUG -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-all -fvisibility-inlines-hidden" -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DWITH_EIGEN=OFF -DWITH_JASPER=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_TIFF=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DWITH_CUFFT=OFF -DWITH_WEBP=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$1/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake $1
```

Comment: From where did you get aarch64-linux-android-clang3.5? If you built it, then can you please post steps for building?

Comment: IIRC, it was symlink to existing clang binary in the NDK distribution in question - just to trick OpenCV toolchain into thinking there is a new version of clang. But since NDK provides its own official cmake toolchain, I use that for building OpenCV.